# Script to display a pop-up and then kills a windows process

Tags: windows, vbscript, powershell-3.0, packaging, sccm

I'm trying to deploy an application through SCCM 2012 for Windows7 (x86 and x64) that requires to notify the user that his Microsoft Outlook should be closed before to continue with the installation. It could be either with a Timer or a (Yes / No) choice, then if the user press Yes then it will close Outlook and will continue with the installation otherwise it will send a log file saying the the user cancelled the installation but it can be retried at any time.

So far I just have the installation script that works only to install the applications using a command line script. So, it will just execute some MSI's installations and Windows updates, and then it quits.

The script I have that creates the pop up and that can be called by my CMD file is the following VBScript and was taken from a TechNet article.

```
Const TIMEOUT = 7
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFS = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strPath = Wscript.FullName
strFileVersion = objFS.GetFileVersion(strPath)

iRetVal = objShell.Popup(Wscript.FullName & vbCrLf & _
 "File Version: " & _
 strFileVersion & vbCrLf & _
 "Would you like to close Outlook application and continue with the installation?" _
 ,TIMEOUT,"Outlook Validation",vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

Select Case iRetVal
 Case vbYes
 Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strPath)
 objShell.Popup WScript.FullName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
 "File Version: " & strFileVersion & vbCrLf & _
 "File Size: " & Round((objFile.Size/1024),2) & _
 " KB" & vbCrLf & _
 "Date Created: " & objFile.DateCreated & vbCrLf & _
 "Date Last Modified: " & objFile.DateLastModified & _
 vbCrLf,TIMEOUT
 Wscript.Quit
 Case vbNo
 Wscript.Quit
 Case -1 
 WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Popup timed out."
 Wscript.Quit
End Select
```

So I don't know if there's any useful example that I can use and customize it from there. I'm clueless, blindfolded, I don't see the light. Well you understand my frustration.

Any ideas, examples or links will be really appreciated!!
Thanks & kind regards.
Joel.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'msgbox objItem.name & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If LCase(objItem.name) = "outlook.exe" then 
        If Msgbox("Close Outlook", 33, "Install") = 1 then
            objItem.terminate
        End If
    End If
Next
```

VBScript's Help file - https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

For help with the WMI object use wmic at the command prompt.

`wmic process get /?` (same as `wmic path win32_process get /?`) and `wmic process call /?` list properties and methods.

Comment: Thanks Noodles, I'll verify this one too !

Answer (score 0):

Here my procedure which closes outlook before modifying the profile.
Is is part of a logon script. The show is a logging and informing procedure.

```
sub CloseOutlook
  on error resume next 'to be able to log and continue
  dim objWMIService, colProcessList, objProcess, sResult, oShell
  set oShell         = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  set objWMIService  = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
  set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'OUTLOOK.EXE'")

  for Each objProcess in colProcessList
    show "outlook is being closed"
    objProcess.Terminate()
    if Err <> 0 then
      show "Error while closing outlook: " & err.Description
    end if
    sResult = oShell.Popup("Outlook is being closed, profile is configured")
  next

end sub
```

If you want confirmation from the user you will have to use a MsgBox instead.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll take a look into it !

Comment: don't thank me, give me a vote 8:) or better accept the answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not faffing about with warnings and closing Outlook, but instead configure the advert to run when no users are logged in. Less chance for problems or accidentally miss-clicked "oh no you lost my emails" situations.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your recommendation, but it was already taken in account that deployments will be tested on the worst conditions to avoid any failure. Inform the user for my deployment is the best chance to avoid any case of  failure or questions like: "Ohh, my application is not been installed yet, why I'm the only one missing on the deployment?" Answer : After analyse the log files, you didn't closed your Outlook applicaiton, so the installation failed.